# I can't play UDP video stream whit LibVLCSharp

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, libvlcsharp

I am beginning to learn how to use the **LibVLCSharp library**. Right now I am trying to play a streaming video that comes to me in multicast UDP, 224.XX.XX.XX:PORT. The problem is that said video comes to me without format.

I get to reproduce it in cmd with:
`vlc udp://@224.XX.XX.XX:PORT --demux=mp4v --rawvid-fps=12`

This is mi code:

```
public void PlayURLFile(string file)
{
    var media = new Media(_libVLC, "udp://@224.XX.XX.XX:XXXXX");
    media.AddOption(":demux=mp4v");
    media.AddOption(":rawvid-fps=12");

    _mp.Play(media);
    isPlaying = true;
}
```

When executing it does not show me any error.

The videoview I have to show the video shows me the black screen.

I understand that the problem may be that I am not entering AddOption correctly or that the options are different. But after fighting with the code and looking at documentation, I can't find an answer that is clarifying.

**Can someone help me?**

**Greetings and thank you.**

Comment: when you say you reproduce in cmd, you mean you actually get it working in CMD?

Comment: enable debug verbose logs and share them in full here please

Comment: Yes, in cmd "Windows terminal" it plays it without problems.

Comment: share full verbose logs with libvlc then

Comment: Whit the command "vlc udp://@224.XX.XX.XX:PORT --demux=mp4v --rawvid-fps=12" in VLC.exe binder.

Answer (score 0):

Give the following options in the `LibVLC` ctor instead.

```
new LibVLC("--demux=mp4v", "--rawvid-fps=12");
```